# What is aspNetCompatibilityEnabled exactly?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

Some SO threads have explanations about why you should set aspNetCompatibilityEnabled to false for some wcf services but what does this feature do exactly?

Comment: the property value determines if service is allowed access to the asp.net managed http runtime.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wenlong/archive/2006/01/23/516041.aspx

Comment: detailed http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wenlong/archive/2006/01/23/516041.aspx